# How to add multiple e-signatures to a pdf via pdfbox and java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, signature

I have a pdf signed with a digital certificate.  The content of the pdf (form fields) must not be changed after signature. Adding a signature should be allowed. Now a second person needs to add his digital signature.  Afterwards no more changes to the document are allowed.  How to achieve this?

I was able to create a pdf via java and pdfbox, sign it and check using java that the certificate is valid, that the certificate was used to sign the document.
On stackoverflow I came across the following snippet that adds a signature to a pdf already signed but I don't know how to implement it.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) 
{
    load current version of the PDF;
    apply the i'th signature;
    save and sign as new current version of the PDF;
}
```

I would appreciate advice how to implement the above.

Comment: Did you try the CreateSignature or CreateVisibleSignature example from the source code download?

Comment: You say you were able to sign a pdf, with pdfbox I assume. Thus, what exactly is your problem implementing that loop?

Comment: That being said, you say that signing shall change whether further changes to some fields are allowed or not. That may require signature lock dictionary support which pdfbox does not provide out of the box but you have to add.

Comment: yes, having a look at CreateSignature solved my issue.   When I open my document in Acrobat reader now it shows a revision 1, locked against changes by my field signatureField and a certification (by the second signature). In my case the 2nd signature is hidden, but Acrobat reader detects it.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

yes, having a look at CreateSignature solved my issue. When I open my document in Acrobat reader now it shows a revision 1, locked against changes by my field signatureField and a certification (by the second signature). In my case the 2nd signature is hidden, but Acrobat reader detects it. Thanks a lot for the help! –